# Prove the series generated by the sequence diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the positive sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ given by

$$\begin{cases}
x_1&=1,\\
x_{n+1}^2+x_{n+1}x_n^2-x_n^2&=0,\ \forall n\ge 1.
\end{cases}$$
More specifically, the second equation together with condition that the sequence is positive-valued mean that $$ x_{n+1}=\dfrac{-x_n^2+\sqrt{x_n^4+4x_n^2}}{2}>0.$$
Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=+\infty$.

With some ideas from Kaind, it can be seen that
\begin{align*}
    x_{n+1}< x_n\Longleftrightarrow -x_n^2+\sqrt{x_n^4+4x_n^2}< 2x_n\Longleftrightarrow x_n^4+4x_n^2 < (x_n^2+2x_n)^2=x_n^4+4x_n^3+4x_n^2.
\end{align*}
Since the latter inequality is true, we have $x_{n+1}< x_n$ for all $n,$ which means $x_n$ is decreasing. Since the sequence is bounded from below by $0,$ its limit exists. Assume the limit is $L,$ we have $L^2+L^3-L^2=0,$ or equivalently, $L=0.$

Thus $x_n\downarrow 0$. It remains to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=+\infty$ and I am still stucking here.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Dat: Your title and the conclusion conflict each other. Please check.

Comment: The quadratic equation has two roots (1 positive and 1 negative), but since the elements in the sequence are positive as stated, $x_{n+1}$ defined uniquely.

Comment: My first line of attack, given that each term is required to be positive, would be to *solve* for $x_{(n+1)}$ by setting up a quadratic equation that involves $x_{(n+1)}$ and $x_n$.  Related question: When you solve the quadratic to produce 2 roots, will one of the roots have to be negative, and therefore rejected?

Comment: @ODETutor yes, that's right, I fixed it. Sorry about this.

Comment: @Kaind I am confused by your comment.  Aren't negative values, such as $x_3 < 0$ *disallowed*?

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, that's correct. I should write explicitly $ x_{n+1}=\dfrac{-x_n^2+\sqrt{x_n^4+4x_n^2}}{2}$ but I think writing as a quadratic equation is nicer and maybe you all can find some hints on it.

Comment: @user2661923 I made a mistake in calculation earlier, sorry about that.

Comment: This isn't as trivial as it looks, because $x_n \rightarrow 0$. (Also FYI, $x_n$ is strictly decreasing)

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer from one of my friends.

We will prove that $x_n\ge 1/n$ by induction. Firstly, notice that
\begin{align*}
    x_{n+1}=\dfrac{-x_n^2+\sqrt{x_n^4+4x_n^2}}{2}=\dfrac{4x_n^2}{2(x_n^2+\sqrt{x_n^4+4x_n^2})}=\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{1+\dfrac{4}{x_n^2}}}.
\end{align*}
Consider the function $f(x)=\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{1+\dfrac{4}{x^2}}}$, we have $x_{n+1}=f(x_n).$ Since $f$ is increasing, supposing $x_n\ge 1/n$, we have
\begin{align*}
    x_{n+1}=f(x_n)\ge f(1/n)=\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{1+4n^2}}.
\end{align*}
It remains to show that $\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{1+4n^2}}\ge \dfrac{1}{n+1}$ which is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
    2n+2\ge 1+\sqrt{1+4n^2}\Longleftrightarrow 2n+1\ge \sqrt{1+4n^2}.
\end{align*}
Squaring both side gives us a always-true expression $4n\ge 0$, and thus $x_{n+1}\ge \dfrac{1}{n+1}.$ Together with $x_1\ge 1$, by induction we have $x_n\ge 1/n$ for all $n.$ Thus $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=\infty.$