# Inequality from real sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Consider the positive sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ given by

$$\begin{cases}
x_1&=1,\\
x_{n+1}^2+x_{n+1}x_n^2-x_n^2&=0,\ \forall n\ge 1.
\end{cases}$$
More specifically, the second equation together with condition that the sequence is positive-valued mean that $$ x_{n+1}=\dfrac{-x_n^2+\sqrt{x_n^4+4x_n^2}}{2}>0.$$

1. Prove that $0< \dfrac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}-x_n< 1$ for all $n$.
2. Can we prove that $\dfrac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}-x_n\rightarrow 1?$

Comment: Did you get a solution from a friend again this time? if so post it here.

Comment: Not yet haha @ODE

Comment: Induction?  Assume it works for $k$, show it works for $k+1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution (not my friend :D) for part 1.

Notice from the post below that $x_n$ is strictly decreasing, and thus $x_n< 1$ for all $n\ge 2$.

[Prove the series generated by the sequence diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4100182/prove-the-series-generated-by-the-sequence-diverges/4100240#4100240)

Then the first part follows easily

$$\dfrac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}-x_n=x_n(\dfrac{1}{x_{n-1}}-1)>0.$$

For the second part, we have
$$\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<x_n+1 \Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{-x_n+\sqrt{x_n^2+4}}{2}<\dfrac{2-x_n^2+\sqrt{x_n^4+4x_n^2}}{2}.$$
This is equivalent to $(1-x_n)(\sqrt{x_n^2+4}-x_n)<2$ and thus
$$(1-x_n)\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x_n^2+4}+x_n}<2\Longleftrightarrow 2-2x_n<\sqrt{x_n^2+4}+x_n\Longleftrightarrow 2-3x_n<\sqrt{x_n^2+4}.$$
The case when $x_n>2/3$ is obvious. When $x_n\le 2/3$, squaring both sides, the latter is equivalent to $x_n< 3/2$ which is always true.

Thus $0< \dfrac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}-x_n< 1$ for all $n$.

I still stuck at proving the convergence of the sequence.